# Can we generate any random variable by transforming a uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with cdf $F$.

**Question:** Can we always find a transformation of a uniform random variable that has the same distribution as $X$? That is, given $U \sim \mathrm{Unif([0,1])}$ can we find a (measurable) function $\varphi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\Pr(\varphi(U) \le x) = F(x)$?

If $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing then we can simply take $\varphi = F^{-1}$ and then
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\varphi(U) \le x) &= \Pr(F^{-1}(U) \le x) \\
                      &= \Pr(U \le F(x)) \\
                      &= F(x).
\end{align*}
(Continuity is needed to that $F^{-1}(u)$ is defined for all $u \in ]0,1[$ and $F$ strictly increasing is needed so that $F^{-1}(u) \le x \Leftrightarrow u \le F(x)$ for all $u \in ]0,1[$.)

But what if $F$ is not continuous or strictly increasing?

Comment: You can define $\phi (x)$ as $\inf \{t: F(t) \geq x\}$.  This will work even if $f$ is not continuous an d strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then we can define $\phi(u) = \inf\{t\in\mathbb{R}: F(t)\geq u\}.$ This is called the generalized inverse. You can now prove that indeed
$$Pr(\phi(U)\leq x) = F(x).$$

The key step is using that $F$ is right-continuous and (not necessarily strictly) increasing, which implies
$$Pr(\phi(U)\leq x) = Pr(U\leq F(x)).$$

You can try to fill in the details yourself.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function).

Comment: I'm not sure if this works if $F$ is not continuous. Note that if $G$ denotes the generalized inverse of $F$ then for $u \in ]0,1[$, $F(G(u)) = u$ only holds if there exists $x$ with $F(x) = u$ (otherwise $F(G(u)) > u$). If $F$ is continuous then for any $u \in ]0,1[$ we can find $x$ with $F(x) = u$. If $F$ is not continuous this need not hold.

Comment: Note that $G$ is non-decreasing (since $F$ is non-decreasing). Hence if $U\leq F(x)$, then also $G(U)\leq G(F(x))\leq x.$ On the other hand, if $G(U)\leq x,$ then $F(G(U))\leq F(x).$ Now note that $F(G(U))\geq U$ by right-continuity of $F.$

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation!