# Does a uniform random variable contain enough randomness to generate any random vector?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U$ be distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$ and let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function of some real-valued random variable $X$. Let $G(y) = \inf\{x:\, F(x) \ge y\}$ be the associated quantile function. Then the transformed random variable $G(U)$ has cdf $F$, i.e.
$$\Pr(G(U) \le x) = F(x)$$
holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728827/451957)). So $U$ "contains enough randomness" to represent any real-valued random variable $X$.

**Question:** Let $U \sim \mathrm{Unif}([0,1])$ and let $(X, Y)$ be a $\mathbb R^2$-valued random vector with cdf $F(x, y) = \Pr(X\le x, Y\le y).$ Can we always find a (measurable) function $\varphi: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ such that for $Z = (Z_1,Z_2) = \varphi(U)$ we have that
$$\Pr(Z_1 \le x, Z_2 \le y ) = F(x, y)$$
holds for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: It looks like Peano-type space-filling curves are measure-preserving, from some poking around on google. This would suggest that the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The high-brow answer: $([0,1],\mathcal B, \lambda)$ is a [standard probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space).

The naive answer: If $X\sim U([0,1])$ its binary digits $B_n$ are iid Bernoulli rvs, where $X=\sum_n B_n/2^n$.  Now write $Y=\sum_k B_{2k}/2^k$ and $Z=\sum_k B_{2k+1}/2^k$ by using the even numbered bits of $X$ and the odd numbered bits of $X$.  You can now check that $Y,Z\sim U([0,1])$ and that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.  To generate $(U,V)$ with arbitrary given joint distribution you could first use your known 1-dimensional $U=G(Y)$ trick to the first coordinate,
where $G$ is the marginal distribution for $U$, and again, with $V=H_U(Z)$, where $H_U$ is the conditional distribution function for $V$ given $U$.

More generally, you can use the same kind of trick to come up with a sequence $X_n$ of iid $U([0,1])$ random variables, and then use the sequence $X_n$ as the return values from successive calls to a  random number generator in an algorithm for simulating the target distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Is my understanding correct? 

We have indep. $\mathrm{Unif}([0,1])$ rv's $Y,Z$ derived from $X$. Take some random vector $(U, V)$.

Let $G$ be the quantile function of $U$. Then 
$$\tilde U=G(X)$$ 
has the same distribution as $U$.

For each $u \in \mathbb R$ let $F_V(\cdot|u)=F_V(\cdot|U=u)$ be the cdf of a regular conditional distribution of $V$ given $U=u$. Let $H_V(\cdot|u)$ be the associated quantile function. Define a new rv by plugging in both $Z$ and $\tilde U$:
$$\tilde V = H_V(Z|\tilde U).$$
Then
$$(\tilde U, \tilde V)$$
has the same distribution as $(U, V).$

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Great, thank you!